# Syntax error with exec call in Python

Tags: python, syntax, exec

Quick python question about the exec command. I'm have Python 2.7.6 and am trying to make use of the exec to run some code stored in a .txt file. I've run into a syntax error and am not entirely sure what is causing it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/parser.py", line 46, in <module>
        try_code(block)
   File "<string>", line 1
        x = 'Hello World!'
            ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I initially thought it was complaining about carriage returns, but when I tried to edit them .replace them with ' ' I still received this error message. I've tried variations to see what appears to be the issue and it always declares the error as the first ' or " the program encounters when it runs exec.

Here is the try_code(block) method

```
def try_code(block):
    exec block
```

And the main body of the program

```
inputFile = open('/Users/XYZ/Desktop/test.txt', 'r+')

starter = False
finished = False
check = 1
block = ""

for val in inputFile:
    starter = lookForStart(val)
    finished = lookForEnd(val)

    if lookForStart:
        check = 1
    elif finished:
        try_code(block)

    if check == 1:
        check = 0
    elif finished == False:
        block = block + val
```

Basically I'm trying to import a file (test.txt) and then look for some embedded code in it. To make it easier I surrounded it with indicators, thus starter and finished. Then I concatenate all the hidden code into one string and call try_code on it. Then try_code attempts to execute it (it does make it there, check with print statements) and fails with the Syntax error.

As a note it works fine if I have hidden something like...

```
x = 5
print x
```

so whatever the problem is appears to be dealing with strings for some reason.

---

### EDIT

It would appear that textedit includes some extra characters that aren't displayed normally. I rewrote the test file in a different text editor (text wrangler) and it would seem that the characters have disappeared. Thank you all very much for helping me solve my problem, I appreciate it.

Comment: What is the content of /Users/XYZ/Desktop/test.txt ?

Comment: Its just gibberish except for the hidden code. It's about 20 lines and about 15 lines down I have x = 'Hello World' and then after that 'print x'. Followed by more gibberish.

Comment: @user2998189 -- Can you give us the actual content of `block` right before you try to `exec` it?

Comment: @mgilson -- Absolutely, right before execute block is "x = 'Hello World' [NEW LINE] print x"  The new line doesn't show up like that in the text, but I don't know how to make it display as a new line in the comments.

Comment: @user2998189 -- try  `print repr(block)`.

Comment: @mgilson -- Interesting, I'll have to look up that command, but that one doesn't fail, but has some weird output... "'x = \xe2\x80\x98Hello World\xe2\x80\x99\nprint x\n'

Comment: What are you using? That ` \xe2\x80\x98` character is the `à` character.

Comment: Just using my text editor, when I open the file it's just regular keyboard characters. Is there a key combination that makes that character?

Comment: I have a french keyboard, so i know that. But just in the python shell: `print u'\xe2\x80\x98'`.

Comment: The issue was probably that your apostrophes were actually *curly* apostropes, `‘’` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a character encoding issue. Unless you've [explicitly declared character encoding of your Python source code at the top of the file](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/); it is 'ascii' by default on Python 2.

The code that you're trying to execute contains non-ascii quotes:

```
>>> print b'\xe2\x80\x98Hello World\xe2\x80\x99'.decode('utf-8')
‘Hello World’
```

To fix it; use ordinary single quotes instead: `'Hello World'`.

You can check that `block` doesn't contain non-ascii characters using decode method: `block.decode('ascii')` it raises an exception if there are.

A gentle introduction into the topic: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)
by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).